# Google OAuth 2 Request invalid_request for Native Mac App redirect_uri

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, aswebauthenticationsession

I am using `ASWebAuthenticationSession` to try and authenticate with Google's OAuth 2.0 API in a native Mac app. I registered my app in the Google Developer Console as a `Desktop` type app like this:

[image]

I construct my URL like this:

```
func createGmailURL() -> String{
  var url = String.init()

  url.append("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
  url.append("?client_id=*****.apps.googleusercontent.com")
  url.append("&redirect_uri=cova://oauth/gmail")
  url.append("&response_type=code")
  url.append("&scope=https://mail.google.com/")
    
  return url
}
```

I then initiate the request like this:

```
let url = createGmailURL()
    
guard let authURL = URL(string: url) else { return }
let scheme = "cova"
   
let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: authURL, callbackURLScheme: scheme){ callbackURL, error in
  ...
}
```

Google seems to reject my request because of something related to the `redirect_uri`.

[image]

I can't for the life of me see what I've done wrong. It seems Google doesn't want to allow me to use a custom URI. Do I have to change the app type to something else? Does `Desktop` not apply to Mac apps?

Comment: redirect uri for installed apps is **redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob**  did we already address this question in https://stackoverflow.com/q/71098468/1841839?

Comment: Answer to this issue is found here, yes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71098468/1841839