# Google OAuth in Desktop Mac App - Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, aswebauthenticationsession

I am trying to authenticate to Google OAuth 2 via a native Mac app. I set up my app in the Google Developer Console as a `Desktop` application, and there is nowhere to specify a `redirect_uri`. As I understand it, those are only available to web applications.

But in composing my request in Swift using `ASWebAuthenticationSession`, my resulting authentication URL is like this (line breaks added for legibility):

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
client_id=******.apps.googleusercontent.com&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=pro.cova%3A%2F&
scope=profile%2520email%2520https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

My app's custom URL type is `pro.cova:/`.

I'm getting this error from Google:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

What mismatch could be happening if there isn't one specified in the Google Developer Console?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that when building a native Mac app, you have to **create "iOS" API credentials** in the Google Developer Console. When setting it up, you have to specify your bundle ID like this: `pro.cova`

When you set the `redirect_uri` in your `ASWebAuthenticationSession` request, it must have a `:/` at the end like this: `redirect_uri=pro.cova:/`

But the `callbackURLScheme` in your `ASWebAuthenticationSession` is without the `:/` so it's just `pro.cova`.

I wish Google's API docs said "iOS or Mac" for the API credential options.

Comment: You saved my time @Clifton. this should be a 100 times accepted answer.